# Adding hosts to Ansible host file

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have been trying to add a host name to my hosts file using an Ansible playbook. My Ansible play look as below and my host file resides at `/etc/ansible/hosts`:

```
- name: adding host playbook
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
  - name: add host to ansible host file
    add_host:
      name: myvm.cloud.azure.com
      groups: mymasters
```

Playbook executes successfully, but the new host name is not added to the Ansible hosts file. Can anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 8):

[`add_host` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/add_host_module.html) does not add a host to your inventory file, but instead creates and adds a host to an inventory existing only in memory. You can use this inventory in subsequent plays, but it won't be saved to a file.

If you really wanted to add a host to the inventory file with Ansible, you'd need to use a regular file-editing module, like [`lineinfile`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lineinfile_module.html) or [`blockinfile`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/blockinfile_module.html).

---

You can also trick [`inifile` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ini_file_module.html) to handle the Ansible inventory, but it's really a hack, as the inventory file does not really have a proper INI-file structure:

```
- ini_file:
    dest: /etc/ansible/hosts
    section: mymasters
    option: myvm ansible_host
    value: myvm.cloud.azure.com
    no_extra_spaces: yes
```

Comment: You could probably have fun with making your inventory a directory too- that way automated entries could stay in their own file.

Answer (score 5):

You can use template to create hosts file.

**Task File**

```
---
- name: Create HostsFile
  hosts: development
  user: vagrant
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo

  tasks:
    - name: Run the Template
      template: src=hostsFile.j2 dest=/tmp/file.conf owner=root group=root
```

Template File :- HostsFile.j2

```
{{ ansible_managed }}

127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6


{% for group in groups %}
{% if groups[group] and group != 'all' %}
{% for host in groups[group] %}
{{hostvars[host].ansible_default_ipv4.address}} {{ ansible_hostname }}
{% endfor %}

{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```