# How to deploy a custom VM with ansible and run subsequent steps on the guest VM via the host?

Tags: ansible, virtual-machine, inventory

I have a playbook that I run to deploy a guest VM onto my target node.
After the guest VM is fired up, it is not available to the whole network, but to the host machine only.
Also, after booting up the guest VM, I need to run some commands **on** that guest to configure it and make it available to all the network members.

```
---
- block:
  - name: Verify the deploy VM script
    stat: path="{{ deploy_script }}"
    register: deploy_exists
    failed_when: deploy_exists.stat.exists == False
    no_log: True

  rescue:
  - name: Copy the deploy script from Ansible
    copy:
      src: "scripts/new-install.pl"
      dest: "/home/orch"
      owner: "{{ my_user }}"
      group: "{{ my_user }}"
      mode: 0750
      backup: yes
    register: copy_script

- name: Deploy VM
  shell: run my VM deploy script

<other tasks>

- name: Run something on the guest VM
  shell: my_other_script
  args:
     cdir: /var/scripts/

- name: Other task on guest VM
  shell: uname -r

<and so on>
```

How can I run those subsequent steps on the guest VM via the host?
My only workaround is to populate a new inventory file with the VMs details and add the use the host as a bastion host.

```
[myvm]
myvm-01 ansible_connection=ssh ansible_ssh_user=my_user ansible_ssh_common_args='-oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ProxyCommand="ssh -A -W %h:%p someuser@host_machine"'
```

However, I want everything to happen on a single playbook, rather than splitting them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding hosts to Ansible host file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41330003/adding-hosts-to-ansible-host-file)

Comment: @techraf He installs a new machine and wants to do something with the new machine, which makes it necessary to add the new machine to the inventory. Everything else has to be done in `.ssh/config`, which is not an Ansible problem.

Comment: @ceving Well, plausible :-) But then the answer is hinted in that other question, not the answer.

Comment: @ceving My problem is that I can't continue the rest of the tasks on the VM, even though I can use add_host.

Comment: See [here](http://sshmenu.sourceforge.net/articles/transparent-mulithop.html) how to do SSH multi-hops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved it myself.
I managed to dynamically add the host to the inventory and used a group:vars for the newly created hosts to use the VM manager as a bastion host

Playbook:

```
---
  hosts: "{{ vm_manager }}"
  become_method: sudo
  gather_facts: False

  vars_files:
    - vars/vars.yml
    - vars/vault.yml

  pre_tasks:

  - name: do stuff here on the VM manager
    debug: msg="test"

  roles:
    - { role: vm_deploy, become: yes, become_user: root }

  tasks:
  - name: Dinamically add newly created VM to the inventory
    add_host:
      hostname: "{{ vm_name }}"
      groups: vms
      ansible_ssh_user: "{{ vm_user }}"
      ansible_ssh_pass: "{{ vm_pass }}"

- name: Run the rest of tasks on the VM through the host machine
  hosts: "{{ vm_name }}"
  become: true
  become_user: root
  become_method: sudo

  post_tasks:
  - name: My first task on the VM
    static: no
    include_role: 
      name: my_role_for_the_VM
```

Inventory:

```
[vm_manager]
vm-manager.local

[vms]
my-test-01
my-test-02

[vms:vars]
ansible_connection=ssh 
ansible_ssh_common_args='-oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ProxyCommand="ssh -A -W %h:%p username@vm-manager.local"'
```

Run playbook:

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts -vv playbook.yml -e vm_name=some-test-vm-name
```