# Ansible | Deploy VM then run additional playbooks against new host?

Tags: ansible, vmware

I am fairly new to Ansible.  I have created an Ansible role that contains the following tasks that will deploy a vm from a template, then configure the VM with custom OS settings:

- create-vm.yml
- configure-vm.yml

I can successfully deploy a VM from a template via the "create-vm" task. But after that is
complete, I would like to continue with the "configure-vm" task.  Since the playbooks/role-vm-deploy.yml file contains "localhost" as shown here...

```
- hosts: localhost
  roles: 
    - vm-deploy
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local
```

... the next task doesn't run successfully because it is attempting to run the task against "localhost" and not the new VM hostname.  I have since added the following to the end of the "create-vm" task...

```
- name: Add host to group 'just_created'
  add_host:
    name: '{{ hostname }}.{{ domain }}'
    groups: just_created
```

...but I'm not quite sure what to do with it. I can't quite wrap my head around what else I need to do and how to call the new hostname in the "configure-vm" task instead of localhost.

I am executing the playbook via CLI

```
# ansible-playbook playbooks/role-vm-deploy.yml
```

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46339011/how-to-deploy-a-custom-vm-with-ansible-and-run-subsequent-steps-on-the-guest-vm), which was kind of helpful
I also saw the [dynamic inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_dynamic_inventory.html) documentation, but it's a bit over my head at this juncture.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you!

Here are the contents for the playbooks and tasks

```
### playbooks -> role-vm-deploy.yml
- hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - vm-deploy
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local

### roles -> vm-deploy -> tasks -> main.yml
- name: Deploy VM
  include: create-vm.yml
  tags:
    - create-vm

- name: Configure VM
  include: configure-vm.yml
  tags:
    - configure-vm
    
### roles -> vm-deploy -> tasks -> create-vm.yml    
- name: Clone the template
  vmware_guest:
    hostname: '{{ vcenter_hostname }}'
    username: '{{ vcenter_username }}'
    password: '{{ vcenter_pwd }}'
    validate_certs: False
    name: '{{ hostname }}'
    template: '{{ template_name }}'
    datacenter: '{{ datacenter }}'
    folder: '/'
    hardware:
      memory_mb: '{{ memory }}'
      num_cpus: '{{ num_cpu }}'
  
    networks:
    - label: "Network adapter 1"
      state: present
      connected: True
      name: '{{ vlan }}'
    state: poweredon
    wait_for_ip_address: yes
    
### roles -> vm-deploy -> tasks -> configure-vm.yml
### This task is what I need to execute on the new hostname, but it attempts to execute on "localhost" ###

# Configure Networking
  - name: Configure IP Address
    lineinfile:
    path: '{{ network_conf_file }}'
    regexp: '^IPADDR='
    line: 'IPADDR={{ ip_address }}'

  - name: Configure Gateway Address
    lineinfile:
    path: '{{ network_conf_file }}'
    regexp: '^GATEWAY='
    line: 'GATEWAY={{ gw_address }}'
    
### roles -> vm-deploy -> defaults -> main.yml
  - All of the variables reside here including "{{ hostname }}.{{ domain }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You got so close! The trick is to observe that a playbook is actually a `list` of plays (the yaml objects that are `{"hosts": "...", "tasks": []}`), and the targets of subsequent plays don't have to exist when the playbook starts -- presumably for this very reason. Thus:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  roles: 
    - vm-deploy
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local
  # or wherever you were executing this -- it wasn't obvious from your question
  post_tasks:
  - name: Add host to group 'just_created'
    add_host:
      name: '{{ hostname }}.{{ domain }}'
      groups: just_created

- hosts: just_created
  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: hello from the newly created {{ inventory_hostname }}
```

Comment: Thank you kindly for the response.  Perhaps I am unclear what file to add to.  I added the "post-tasks" section to the `playbooks/role-vm-deploy.yml`, and the "hosts - just created" section to the `/roles/vm-deploy/tasks/create-vm.yml` file?  

I also tried adding all lines of the suggestion to `playbooks/role-vm-deploy.yml`.  

Lastly, I combined both role tasks to a single playbook (maybe the role was confusing me), but it still says `fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {.....` when it attempts to access the new hostname.

Comment: Please don't use the comments for code; instead [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63237179/edit) to show your new playbook and the new error message. I'll also be honest that I've never used `post_tasks:`, so it's possible that's not the right construct, but your question wasn't a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so nor was my answer

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question (end) with the contents of the playbook/tasks